# Integrating $\int \frac{z-z'}{\left(x'^2+y'^2+(z-z')^2\right)^{3/2}}dV$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How to do this integral?

```
Integrate[(z - z\[Prime])/(x\[Prime]^2 + 
   y\[Prime]^2 + (z - z\[Prime])^2)^(
 3/2), {x\[Prime], y\[Prime], z\[Prime]} \[Element] 
  Ball[{0, 0, 0}, R]]
```

Comment: Does it actually have a closed form answer?  Usually I manually construct asymptotic approximations to those integrals, and not bother Mathematica's `Integrate`.  And I use `Integrate` normally for trivial things to confirm constant factors/signs at intermediate steps of my manual calculations.

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, this is just the z-component of the electric field corresponding to a uniformly charged sphere centered at the origin. When z > R it should be ~ 1/z^2 and when z < R it should be ~ z.

Comment: It can do the indefinite integral.  Maybe its having trouble with your integration limits.

Comment: Dear OP, I find your question interesting, but I am also annoyed by the negativity in your language. Wrong place.

Comment: @user293787 I will change it to suit your tastes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It helps to guide the integration, in the same way as it would be done manually.

Convert to spherical coordinates:

```
(z - z1)/(x1^2 + y1^2 + (z - z1)^2)^(3/2) /.
    {x1 -> r Sin[θ] Cos[φ],
     y1 -> r Sin[θ] Sin[φ],
     z1 -> r Cos[θ]} // FullSimplify

(*    (z - r Cos[θ])/(r^2 + z^2 - 2 r z Cos[θ])^(3/2)    *)
```

Integrate in $\theta$:

```
Assuming[r > 0 && z > 0, 
  Integrate[(z - r Cos[θ])/(r^2 + z^2 - 2 r z Cos[θ])^(3/2) * 2 π r^2 Sin[θ],
            {θ, 0, π}]]

(*    -2 π r^2 (-1 + Sign[r - z])/z^2    *)
```

Radial integral:

```
Assuming[z > 0 && R > 0, 
  Integrate[-2 π r^2 (-1 + Sign[r - z])/z^2, {r, 0, R}] // FullSimplify]
```

$$
\begin{cases}
 \frac{4 \pi  R^3}{3 z^2} & R<z \\
 \frac{4 \pi  z}{3} & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I guess it is best to avoid version 13.1 functions since it's new at the time of writing but since version 13.1, change of variables in integrals can be done with the function [IntegrateChangeVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) like this (example taken from the documentation): `IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(
  3/2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -Sqrt[4 - x^2], Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {z, 
   2 - Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2], 
   2 + Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]}], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, 
 "Cartesian" -> "Spherical"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment. I will consider a related problem in 2 dimensions using integration over a `Ball` of radius 1. I understand what the correct solution is (see the plot below) and how to obtain it, but here I am only interested in how Mathematica deals with integration over a region such as a `Ball`.

Define

```
f[y_]:=1/Pi*Integrate[(y-Y)/(X^2+(y-Y)^2),
                      {X,Y}\[Element]Ball[{0,0},1]];
```

**Plot.**

[image]

This was generated using `Plot[f[y],{y,-2,2},AxesLabel->{"y","f[y]"}]`.

**Exact numerical evaluation.** This seems to work:

```
{f[0],f[1/2],f[1],f[2]}
(* {0,1/2,1,1/2} *)
```

**Symbolic evaluation.** This does not work:

```
f[y]
(* 1/(2*y) *)

Assuming[0<y<1,f[y]]
(* 0 *)

Assuming[1<y,f[y]]
(* 1/y *)
```

The first and second are wrong. I use Version 12.3 if it matters.